# Extract string which is separated by dots followed by another string

Tags: bash, shell

I need to get the browser version which is followed by browser name and / in my log file. Example

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0.5.7
```

Here i would like to extract the version which comes after Firefox i.e (17.0.5.7). I have tried the following, but no success. As i am using AIX, i am unable to make use of -O flag.

```
grep -w 'Firefox\/[^ ,]\+' $line
sed 's/^.*\(Firefox\/[^ ,]*\).*$/\1/' $line
```

Also i need use the command inside while do loop like below

```
while read -r line
do
case $line in    
*Firefox*) print "<browser Firefox>\"" command_to_be_executed $line "\"</browser>";;
*) print "<browser>\"Unknown\"</browser>";;
esac
done < filename
```

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's the last field in the line, you can do:

```
awk -F'[ /]' '$(NF-1)=="Firefox"{print $NF}' file.log
```

It prints the lines which checks whether the it is "Firefox" and prints the version followed.

---

Simply do echo on `line` and get the version.

```
while read -r line
do
case $line in    
*Firefox*) version=$(echo $line | awk -F'[ /]' '{print $NF}' )
print "<browser Firefox>\"" $version "\"</browser>";;
*) print "<browser>\"Unknown\"</browser>";;
esac
done < filename
```

Comment: Thank you. But i would be using this code for other browsers too which may not be the last field. Also i need to use the command inside while do loop. Any suggestions please ??

Comment: @user1746666 You can use the awk inside the case. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have used your suggestion to fit the code inside case. For other browsers which are not at the last field, i made use of other answers.

Answer (score 1):

what was wrong with your version of sed is a brace before Firefox.Just change as below:

```
sed 's/^.*Firefox\/\([^ ,]*\).*$/\1/' your_file
```

the above should work.
other methods are:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/Firefox/){split($i,a,"/");print a[2]}}' file_name
```

also in sed(worked for me):

```
sed -e 's/.*Firefox\/\([^\s]*\)/\1/g' your_file
```

in perl:

```
perl -F -ane 'foreach (@F){if(/Firefox/){$_=~s/Firefox\///g;print $_}}' your_file
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesnt work inside while do loop. It may because of print. I have updated my question for the same. Any suggestions please ??

Comment: I made use of the suggestion given by KingsIndian and used your code inside case. Hope i can mark all the answers as correct :-). Thanks for your timely help.

Answer (score 1):

A small correction to your sed attempt:

```
$ sed 's|.*Firefox/\([^ ,]*\).*|\1|' file
17.0.5.7
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesnt work inside while do loop. It may because of print. I have updated my question for the same. Any suggestions please ??

Comment: I made use of the suggestion given by KingsIndian and used your code inside case. Hope i can mark all the answers as correct :-). Thanks for your timely help.